# Identity function в Itertools.groupby

Tags: python, python-3.x

Читал документацию по python, а конкретно по функции `groupby` и наткнулся на такую фразу которую понять не в состоянии.

> itertools.groupby(iterable, key=None)
> Make an iterator that returns consecutive keys and groups from the iterable. The key is a function computing a key value for each element.**If not specified or is None, key defaults to an identity function and returns the element unchanged.**

Объясните пожалуйста что такое `identity function` и что же происходит в функции `groupby` если ключ отсутствует? Было бы не плохо на каком нибудь примере.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Identity function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function) по-русски – [тождественное отображение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Проще говоря, это функция, которая возвращает свой аргумент без изменений

```
def identity(x):
    return x
```

Подобная функция есть, например, в библиотеке [toolz](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.functoolz.identity), да и вообще в мире функционального программирования она очень востребована.

Вызов `groupby` без параметра `key`

```
itertools.groupby(iterable)
```

по результату будет совпадать со следующим вызовом

```
itertools.groupby(iterable, key=lambda x: x)
```

т.е. в качестве ключа группировки будет использован сам элемент последовательности, и в одну группу попадут только равные элементы, расположенные последовательно.

```
>>> [(k, g) for k, [*g] in itertools.groupby([1,2,2,1,3,3,3,1,1])]
[(1, [1]), (2, [2, 2]), (1, [1]), (3, [3, 3, 3]), (1, [1, 1])]
```

Answer (score 1):

`identity function` - в данном случае функция, которая возвращает аргумент (операнд) не измененным. Если какая-то функция (в вашем случае - метод `groupby`) требует на вход ключ в виде функции, которая вычисляется для каждого члена итератора, то передать в нее просто, скажем, число, не получится.

Если вы передадите в groupby ключ равный `None` или вообще не передадите ключ, то фактически ключ будет вычисляться как-то так:

```
def identity_func(operand):
    return operand
```

То есть, группируемый объект у вас останется неизмененным. О чем и говориться в документации.